# Extract text from a popup using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Consider:

[image]

I need to find a way how I could get the text from the popup using Selenium/core Java, so that I can compare the text with expected data.

Is there a way I could extract the text from the popup?

A screenshot is attached.

Comment: You need to tell us what you have tried already. As far as I know Selenium, this shouldn't be any different than getting text from non-popups, except for the fact that you might have to trigger the popup to be visible , before getting the text... As the question is now, I can't answer better than referring to the documentation of Selenium. You need to specify you problem a little bit better. There is a reason why SO guidelines state that you need to include what you have tried.

Comment: unfortunately I do not know a way to get entire text from the main window itself. Could you please suggest how I could achieve that . Thanks

Comment: I really can't without any more information about the structure of the HTML, and your current level of understanding of Selenium. This should really be one of the most basic things possible to do in selenium. You pretty much need to identify which element the text is in, and use the WebDriver.findElement(*your choice of locator*)... and then getText(). If you've already tried that, let us know why it doesn't work, or where in this process you can't get it.

Comment: Now, if the popup was in another frame, there is a small trick that needs to be done, before being able to select the element, but I do not think that is the case here. But answer me these questions: are you familiar with finding elements, and creating WebElement objects? Have you tried to find the element which contains the text? Do you understand the HTML structure, and how to find the element in the source code/firebug console? are you able to locate the WebElement using WebDriver.findElement(By by)? have you tried WebElement.getText()?

Comment: Yes I have done the above. tried     WebElement popupBody = driver.findElement(By.className("row")); System.out.println(popupBody.getText().toString());

Comment: however the above does not return any text

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant HTML and what code you have tried and the result. Until then, we can't help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

If you **inspect** the element which has the focus.
This is possible with all common browsers via *development tools* or use the SeleniumIDE Plugin for Firefox to get information about that page and build locators.
Often framework are used (like bootstrap) to ensure a consistent layout so a CSS-locator might look like:

```
var popupBody = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.modal-dialog div.content div.body")
```

Note that in this case Bootstrap would not the call the class *'popup'* but *'modal-dialog'*. The locator might furthermore vary depending on the inner structure. As mentioned inspect the element (or share the HTML code so we can suggest concrete locator).

By this you get a normal WebElement ala Selenium where you can get the Text

```
// use the element
.. popupBody.Text ..
```