# How to scrape a json element using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape data from a json element. Clicking on the element opens up a pop up which contains the data I need.

I tried to click on the element using selenium but it returns `None`.

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('View details').click()
```

URL - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping

Desired Output - (This app has access to:
Storage
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
read the contents of your USB storage
Contacts
read your contacts
find accounts on the device
Microphone
record audio
SMS
read your text messages (SMS or MMS)
receive text messages (SMS)
send SMS messages
Photos/Media/Files
modify or delete the contents of your USB storage
read the contents of your USB storage
Camera
take pictures and videos
Phone
read phone status and identity
Identity
add or remove accounts
find accounts on the device
Wi-Fi connection information
view Wi-Fi connections
Location
precise location (GPS and network-based)
approximate location (network-based)
Device ID & call information
read phone status and identity
Other
read Home settings and shortcuts
receive data from Internet
prevent device from sleeping
view network connections
control flashlight
use accounts on the device
install shortcuts
create accounts and set passwords
connect and disconnect from Wi-Fi
full network access
control vibration
run at startup)

**This is the json element**

[image: This is the json element]

**This contains the required text**
[image: This contains the required text]

Comment: post url and desired output

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: It returns None. How do I get the text?

Comment: can you share html cofde?

Comment: I have posted the URL. You can get it from there

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273881/extract-text-from-popup-using-selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `None` statement tells nothing to us without the context, i.e. a piece of code which navigates to the page and clicks the link. The error might live at any place.

Few hints:

1. Always use [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) in order to wait until the element is present, something like:

   ```
   driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping")

   WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "View details")))
   driver.find_element_by_link_text('View details').click()

   WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'This app has access to')]")))
   permissions = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'This app has access to')]/parent::*")
   ```

   More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)
2. In order to get the text of the HTML element you can use [`innerText` DOM object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) property using [`get_attribute` function](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) like:

   ```
   text = permissions.get_attribute("innerText")
   ```
3. That's it, you should get the desired text as the variable:

   [image]